# jquery datatables export excel to chinese

Tags: datatables

Am using jquery datatables with tools to export PDF, Excel, CSV etc. However as the site is in Chinese (setLocale) when we export the characters aren't set to **UTF-8** (I believe) and show **åº—é“º** type characters rather than the Chinese (地摘) .

> Does anyone know where the export character can be set, for that
>   matter PDF export results in? instead of characters.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the result is because of the viewer. That is when opened in excel you get the funny characters, when open in UTF8 view able editor you can see the Chinese.